# Extra time to serve requests using thinking sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, thinking-sphinx

I'm trying to figure out why my rails server is taking lots of extra time to serve requests now that I switch to thinking sphinx from solr.

I'm getting things like

```
Completed 200 OK in 1242ms (Views: 248.8ms | ActiveRecord: 89.3ms | Sphinx: 5.3ms)
```

and

```
Completed 200 OK in 881ms (Views: 4.7ms | ActiveRecord: 7.1ms | Sphinx: 29.4ms)
```

I'm trying to use Thinking Sphinx to serve up JSON for an autocomplete drop down. I'm trying to figure out where the bottle neck is. I've tried running lots of benchmarks, but I can't seem to find it. When I run stuff from the console it seems snappy. Any ideas about why I'm seeing these kinds of render times?

Before I switched the render times were effectively the sum of the Views and ActiveRecord so in the ballpark of <300ms.

I should also note that I'm only seeing the bottlenecks on pages that interact with use search, which is why I'm thinking that it may be due to Thinking Sphinx.

Comment: I'm giving this a try http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/advanced_config.html#indexed-models

Comment: turns out this was only really a problem in the development environment. I loaded my project in a staging environment and there was no issue. I'm still curious what's going on in the development environment that makes it take so much longer.

Comment: Up until the very latest release, TS was loading I18n on every request (due to how Rails 2.3 and earlier behaves). 2.0.9 removes that behaviour, as it's not an issue in Rails 3.x - so that could also be a cause of the speed issue.

Comment: That said, that's a very slow view - but give TS 2.0.9 a try and let me know if it improves the situation in development.

Comment: I am running TS 2.0.9. When I created my local staging environment my load times were <40 ms for my json requests and ~300 ms for other pages.